# How to import function into main file in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am splitting my main.py file into multiple files. I have a main.py file and another user.py file. So I just want to import function of user.py into main.py file and @app.route will remain stay in main.py file. Is there any other option except Blueprint in Flask?

Any help would be appreciated?

```
#main.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from user import about

@app.route('/')
def hello():
   return "Hello"

@app.route('/about')
about()
```

This about() part is giving me syntax error

---

```
#user.py

def about():
   return "Hey There!"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this. just define route but call the function inside it

```
#main.py
from user import about

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from user import about

@app.route('/')
def hello():
   return "Hello"

@app.route('/about')
def hey():
    return about()
```

Comment: it won't work if you copy paste it right away. you need to import file and method of that file then you can call it.

Comment: Aforementioned code was an example. Actually I am implementing it on different code but the way I am doing is the same way.